# Can I use a For loop with a Nodelist?

Tags: javascript, html, nodelist

Basically I have some HTML code that is a tree, I was traverse the Nodelist for it and and assign certain `classes` to nodes if they have children, here's a snippet:

```
<li id='test' class="parentNode">
  <button class="customer-btn button"><a href='#'>Customer 6</a></button>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href='#'>Customer A</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="parentNode">
    <button class="customer-btn button"><a href='#'>Customer 7</a></button>
    <ul>
      <li>
      <a href='#'> Customer A</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
```

This is my Javascript:

```
parent_list = document.getElementsByTagName("LI");
  var i;
  $(document).ready(function() {
    for (i=0; i < parent_list.length; i++){
        children = $(i).find('LI');
        document.getElementById('check').innerHTML = children;
    }
    });
```

The `for` loop I have return `[object Object]`, what's the best what to do this?

Comment: You don't need jQuery for this, it will only slow down your script and add unnecessary dependencies.

Comment: To answer your question "Can I use a For loop with a Nodelist?": **Yes you can**, because a NodeList has a `length` attribute and can be indexed like an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You don't need jQuery](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/).

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', run );
function run() {

    var allLIElements = document.getElementsByTagName('LI');
    for( var i = 0; i < allLIElements.length; i++ ) {
        var li = allLIElements[i];
        if( li.firstElementChild != null ) {
            li.classList.add('hasChildren');
        }
    }
}
```

Note that this will soon be unnecessary as CSS has the proposed `:has()` pseudo-class which you can use to select elements that meet some criteria.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has

> The `:has()` CSS pseudo-class represents an element if any of the selectors, relative to the:scope of the given element, passed as parameters, matches at least one element. The `:has()` pseudo-class takes a selector list as an argument.

Consider this style rule instead, it will match any `li` element that contains another element. No JavaScript required.

```
li:has(> *) { /* As of early 2017 no browser supports this selector yet! */

}
```

Comment: *"Consider this style rule instead"* How much consideration should really be given to that CSS rule since there's basically zero browser support for it according to your link?

Comment: Thanks that should work well, at least I wasn't too far off. Also that CSS feature would be a god-send

Comment: @squint Because this answer will still be on SO in the future - and as it's looking like `:has()` will be added to the spec eventually I want my answer to be future-proof! :D

Comment: *"...will be added to the spec eventually"* Better keep your fingers crossed. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using jQuery you don't need a for loop

```
$('li').each(function(index, element){
    if($(element).children().length > 0){
        $(element).addClass('myClass')
    }
})
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't meet the OP's criteria: " assign certain classes to nodes if they have children"

Answer (score -2):

You can use a for loop for anything, but your code isn't correct...assigning children to innerHTML isn't a compatible assignment, and doing it in a loop will just result in the element 'check' being assigned multiple times, not with an addition.

If you are using jQuery then use:

```
    $('#check').append(children);
```